# How modify UI Component Option values in custom modules

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have a base module which defines a UI Select component like so:

```
      <field name="type" formElement="select">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <notice>Make a Selection</notice>
            <label>Custom Select</label>
            <dataScope>type</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options>
                        <option name="option1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option 1</item>
                        </option>
                        <option name="option2" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option 2</item>
                        </option>
                    </options>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

This works great and makes a beautiful select like this:

[image]

Now, I want to add possible options in dependent modules. So in the dependent module I would like to add and option:

```
    <field name="type">   
        <settings>
            <notice>Choose Your Option please</notice>
            <label>Modifed Select</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options>
                        <option name="option3" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option 3</item>
                        </option>                            
                    </options>      
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So clearly I can see that two of my modifications were accepted in the dependent module as the label as well as the hint/notice are updated. However the option was not added.

Is it not possible to do this via XML? What are my other choices, given that I want other modules to be able to extend mine in this fashion?

Comment: You can use php class to render your option and another module can create a plugin for your class to append new options in it. Here is the example how to use class for option https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/dcc962efc5ad12717c6eac0f10cf822780dd3f4a/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml#L231

Comment: Thank you @RakeshVarma . That is an option to explore for sure. I just want to confirm whether or not it's not possible to do via XML since the other modifications to ui_components clearly are.